# Change icon on clicking using "toggle"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the same HTML, CSS and Javascript as here: [How to close this menu after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507026/how-to-close-this-menu-after-click)
Please let me know how to change the hamburger icon to a close (x) icon (without using rotation of the icon) after clicking and opening the topnav Nav bar. I tried what is posted here and failed (I did add and try out all that was mentioned there, including the `<i id="click-spanish" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> and <div id="spanish-examples"></div>`): [Change toggle icon on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51484547/change-toggle-icon-on-click)

Answer (score 1):

you can use a variable for class and use onclick function to toggle the variable

```
    let icon = true

    const changeIcon = () => {
    icon = !icon
    }
```

in html you can use like

```
    <i id="click-spanish" onclick="changeIcon()" class={icon ? "fa fa-caret-down":"some other icon"}> </i>
```

Comment: In HTML, I put: `<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"><ul><a href="#">Links:</a><a href="index.html">Home</a><a href="about.html">About</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i id="click-spanish" onclick="changeIcon()" class={icon ? "&#9947;":"&times;"}></i></a>` & `let icon = true
    const changeIcon = () => { icon = !icon } $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#click-spanish').click(function() { $('#myTopnav').toggle('1000');
    $(this).toggleClass("&#9947; &times;"); }); });` in javascript but the icons aren't showing up now

Comment: @eisbehr, The icons were showing up before but not now. What to do?

Comment: the responsive dropdown Navbar is also not working on my mobile after I did what you advised. Please help!

Comment: I got a very nice solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259252/change-icon-on-clicking-using-a-toggle