# Change icon on clicking using a "toggle"

Tags: html

I have the same HTML, CSS and Javascript as here: [How to close this menu after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507026/how-to-close-this-menu-after-click) Please let me know how to change the hamburger icon to a close (x) icon (without using rotation of the icon) after clicking and opening the topnav Nav bar.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: As here, where?

Comment: This link could help you: https://codepen.io/rss/pen/vIDKH/. Also there are a lot of sites about CSS Icon Animations. For example here you can choose which you like the most: https://bashooka.com/coding/21-cool-css-hamburger-menu-animations/

Comment: @mplungjan, I have added a link to what I want you people to see, please take a look and tell me what to do. I am still a novice/rookie and forgot to add the link at first

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor, post the code you have and your attempt to change it

Comment: Or do you just want to change `☰` to `✕`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.links').on("click", function() {
    $("#myTopnav").removeClass("responsive");
  });

  $("#toggle").on("click", function() {
    const $nav = $("#myTopnav");
    $nav.toggleClass("responsive");
    $(this).html(
      $nav.hasClass("responsive") ?  "&times;" : "&#9776;"
    )
  });

});
```

```css
ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

ul.topnav li.icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1180px) {
  ul.topnav li:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  ul.topnav li.icon {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:680px) {
  ul.topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li {
    float: none;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul.topnav.responsive li a {
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <li class="links"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li class="links"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li class="links"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="links"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
  <li class="icon">
    <a href="#" id="toggle">&#9776;</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes. Very nice! Thank you!

Comment: How do I make the links show horizontally on a laptop and vertically on a mobile (after clicking the Navbar)?

Comment: That’s a different question -use media queries

Comment: Thanks for the time you made for me and posting a code I could run. Now please tell me how to keep everything (css, javascript and html codes) mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507026/how-to-close-this-menu-after-click and only change the javascript using toggle to get the close icon (x) on opening the responsive top navbar and the hamburger icon on closing it again

Comment: That is what I did, I ONLY changed the ID of the link and the code, That is all

Comment: the dropdown/navbar is not showing up on clicking on mobiles - I deleted all the old css, javascript and html codes and put all that you have typed above. Please let me know what to do now. I am not sure if I can add the url of the website here so please let me know if I am not supposed to and I will remove it, but here is the url: http://www.a1polyclinic.in/Dr.Ramaanand-4.html

Comment: Can you ask another question since I think it’s to do with the media query

Comment: I had used an extra flower bracket at the end of my javascript and was able to correct it. Thanks a lot for everything!